# Wireless and Bluetooth and external display not working

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, drivers, bluetooth

This morning when i connect mY HP Folio 9470M (Ubuntu 14.04 LTS installed) to my docking i see that i don't have external display.

Later i see that Wlan switch is not working and bluetooth also.

It seems that something os disable or motherboard is not so good.

How can i troubleshoot?

Iwconfig says no wireless extensions..

I tried several tests and reboots but still not working

It occurs a month ago and starts to work by miracle again.

No what can we test?

Regards